# Conditional Operator without if...else in java

Tags: java, if-statement

So recently I got a question that how to perform the function of if...else without if...else.
Like if a program is to find the greater between integer `a` and `b`, one would easily write that

```
if (a>b) {
   System.out.println("a is greater");
} else {
   System.out.println("b is greater");
}
```

Is there any other way to do this without `if...else` method?

Comment: `System.out.printf("%d is greater than %d%n", Math.max(a, b), Math.min(a, b));`

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary:

```
System.out.println((a > b ? "a" : "b") + " is greater");
```

Note: Both this code and your code assumes that `a` is not equal to `b`.

---

A more contrived solution would be:

```
switch ((int) Math.signum(Integer.compare(a, b))) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("a is greater");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("b is greater");
}
```

Comment: You cannot `switch` with the result of [Math.signum()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#signum(double)).  It returns `double` or `float`.  And `a - b` can overflow.

Comment: `Math.signum(Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE)` is `1.0`.

Comment: @mokyade I actually don’t care about such edge cases, because it’s not necessary to convey the intent, but since you are persistent, see minor tweak to cater for this nevertheless.

Comment: I'm sorry for being persistent. I like `Integer.compare`.

Comment: @mokyade respect: `Integer.compare()` is better.

Answer (score 0):

we can use the Java Ternary Operator.

```
System.out.println((a > b ? "a" : "b") + " is greater);
```

for more follow this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using `Math`:

```java
int max = Math.max(a, b);
```